# Index a foreign key in Grails / Gorm

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

Using Grails / Gorm, I can define indexes by doing something like:

```
class Person {
    String firstName
    static mapping = {
        table 'people'
        id column: 'person_id'
        firstName column: 'First_Name', index: 'Name_Idx'
    }
}
```

However, if I am using a join table as in:

```
class Employee {
    static hasMany = [projects: Project]

    static mapping = {
        projects joinTable: [name: 'EMP_PROJ',
                             column: 'PROJECT_ID',
                             key: 'EMPLOYEE_ID']
    }
}
```

How do I configure it so that the columns in the join table are indexed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that there isn't any DSL within Grails to do so. However, you can always setup a index in your [hibernate configuration](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/hibernate.html) for these join tables. Here is an example of said configuration file.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> 

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
   '-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN' 
   'http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd'> 

<hibernate-mapping> 
   <database-object> 
      <create>CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON bar (some_id, other_column)</create> 
      <drop/> 
      <dialect-scope name='org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect' /> 
   </database-object> 
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your are using the [database migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) you can use the [createIndex](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_index.html) change set to create an index:

```
changeSet(author: "..", id: "..") {
  createIndex(indexName: "indexname", tableName: "yourtable", unique: "true") {
    column(name: "country_code")
  }
}
```